# using bash (sed/awk) to extract rows AND columns in CSV files?

Tags: bash, csv, sed, awk

Is bash capable of handling extracting rows and columns from csv files?  Hoping I don't have to resort to python..

My 5-column csv file looks like:

```
Rank,Name,School,Major,Year
1,John,Harvard,Computer Science,3
2,Bill,Yale,Political Science,4
3,Mark,Stanford,Biology,1
4,Jane,Princeton,Electrical Engineering,3
5,Alex,MIT,Management Economics,2
```

I only want to extract the 3rd, 4th, and 5th column contents, ignoring the first row, so output looks like:

```
Harvard,Computer Science,3
Yale,Political Science,4
Stanford,Biology,1
Princeton,Electrical Engineering,3
MIT,Management Economics,2
```

So far I can only get awk to print out either each row, or each column of my CSV file, but not specific cols/rows like this case! Can bash do this?

Comment: it's odd that you're struggling to get awk to do this since printing fields (columns) and rows (records) is the most basic thing awk that is designed to do. Makes me think there must be more to this than you've described so far....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash solutions;

**Using IFS**

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=',' read -r rank name school major year; do
    echo -e "Rank\t: $rank\nName\t: $name\nSchool\t: $school\nMajor\t: $major\nYear\t: $year\n"
done < file.csv
IFS=$' \t\n'
```

**Using String Manipulation and Arrays**

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr
while read -r line; do
    arr=(${line//,/ })
    printf "Rank\t: %s\nName\t: %s\nSchool\t: %s\nMajor\t: %s\nYear\t: %s\n" ${arr[@]}
done < file.csv
```

Comment: Fairly unwieldy, but I like the use of arrays which I will probably refer to again at some point. Not to mention it's a bash-only solution.

Comment: this fails to ignore commas in quotes. example csv line: `"some, text",1,2` will be parsed as: `some`, `text`, `1`, `2` instead of `some text`, `1`, `2`

Answer (score 19):

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 { print $3 "," $4 "," $5 }'
```

NR is the current line number, while $3, $4 and $5 are the fields separated by the string given to -F

Comment: You can set `OFS=','` so that you don't have to concatenate commas in the print.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
tail -n+2 file.csv | cut --delimiter=, -f3-5
```

Comment: Most simple and elegant solution yet.

Answer (score 6):

Use `cut` and `tail`:

```
tail -n +2 file.txt | cut -d ',' -f 3-
```

Comment: The OP wanted to skip the first line, that's why we used `tail`.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 1d file.csv | while IFS=, read first second rest; do echo "$rest"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, a simple AWK program.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    # set field separator to comma to split CSV fields
    FS = ","
}

# NR > 1 skips the first line
NR > 1 {
    # print only the desired fields
    printf("%s,%s,%s\n", $3, $4, $5)
}
```

Comment: If you set `OFS=","`, you can simply write `print $3, $4, $5`

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -F, -lane 'if($.!=1){print join ",",@F[2,3,4];}' your_file
```

check [here](http://ideone.com/NFSiGJ)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1d;s/([^,]*,){2}//' file
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 { OFS=",";print $3, $4, $5 }' temp.txt
```

or this

```
sed -re '1d;s/^[0-9],\w+,//g' temp.txt
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation of what your fixes are doing.

Comment: @JonEgerton , in the awk i added the OFS and in sed i made more clearer so that the new users can see what i am matching . in previous answers regex are shhort but hard to comprehend for new user of regex. mine may not be perfect but at least are visible what they are doing. and they work

Answer (score 1):

I have created package for this kind of tasks - [gumba](http://gumba.welldan97.com/)
If you feel comfortable with coffeescript you can give it a try

```
cat file.csv | tail -n +2 | \
gumba "words(',').take((words)-> words.last(3)).join(',')"`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep '^,' outlook.contacts.csv | sed 's/^,\([^,]*\),[^,]*,\([^,]*\),.*/\1 \2/'
```

Get all lines that starts with a `,` then using `sed` to replace blank fields with first and second name.

Be careful for some reason once you paste it changes the line to this so maybe you better to carefully do it manually.

```
grep '^,' outlook.contacts.csv | sed 's/^,([^,]),[^,],([^,]),./\1 \2/'
```