# Use Unix's sed to turn a csv into a javascript object

Tags: javascript, bash, csv, awk, sed

Sorry to post such a rudimentary question, but I'm getting confused by all the different tutorials and examples (and slashes and hyphens and back-ticks oh my) so I figured I would get someone's experienced input.

I have a .csv which is obviously comma seperated that has several hundred lines which looks like this:

`abcd-3096,62#,,100,,,25,,75,3,`
and it should be formatted like so:

```
{name: 'abcd-3096', weight : 62, some-field1: null, class: 100, some-field2: null, some-field3: null, unit-weight : 25, some-field4 : null, capacity : 75,   }
```

I know you'll either want to use `awk` or `sed` in order to replace it, and I'm more than fine with doing the formatting in several commands.

I don't expect anyone to format the whole line for me, but I'm hoping some one can show me how to prepend a column with some some text.  I can't seem to find a reliable explanation of the command anywhere online.

Comment: Will any of the fields in your .csv ever contain a comma?

Comment: No, we can assume that commas only delineate the fields or columns.

Comment: Why not Perl one-liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *negating character classes* like `[^,]` for this:

```
sed -r 's/^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)/{ name: "\1", weight: "\2", somefield1: "\3" }/' file.csv
```

The example uses only 3 groups for simplicity ... but you get the idea.

If your system does not support `sed -r` (extended regex syntax), you need to use `\(group\)` instead of `(group)`:

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/{ name: "\1", weight: "\2", somefield1: "\3" }/' file.csv
```

---

In case you don't *need* to use sed, you can also use bash directly:

```
while IFS=',' read -r name weight somefield1 class somefield2 somefield3 unitweight capacity rest
do
    echo -e "{ name: \"$name\", weight: \"$weight\", somefield1: \"$somefield1\",";
    echo -e " class: \"$class\", somefield2: \"somefield2\" somefield3: \"$somefield3\",";
    echo -e " unitweight: \"$unitweight\", capacity: \"$capacity\" }";
done < file.csv
IFS=$' \t\n'
```

(taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492590/using-bash-sed-awk-to-extract-rows-and-columns-in-csv-files#answer-14493571) answer by koola)

Comment: (All of these solutions assume that you have no commas in your data, as you stated in your comment on your question.)

Comment: This is an excellent answer. For your first example, it looks like you are trying to negate the same thing 3 times. Is that in compensation for the triple comma part of my data?

Comment: `([^,]*)` means *"capture 0 or more characters that are not a comma"*.
So for 2 values the pattern is `([^,]*),([^,]*)`, matching "a value, then a comma, then a value". For each additional group, you'd add `,([^,]*)`.

Comment: So if I wanted to specify for just a single column using sed, how would the following pseudo code: `sed -r /regex field#/'string' field#/`?

Comment: `sed -r 's/([^,]*).*/{ "name": "\1" }/'`. The basic sed replace syntax is `sed 's/pattern/replacement'`. For regular expressions specifically I can recommend a read of http://www.regular-expressions.info/