# Read CSV from bash or perl script

Tags: bash, perl

I have simple simple CSV file as follow (3 columns and 4 rows for that example):

```
A       , B      , C
A       , ”B,C”  , D
“A,B”   , C      , D
A       , B      , ”C,D”
```

How to create script that I can enter the column and the row number and it print me back the content?

Note! that the comma between the quotation marks as a parameter and not as a separator..

edit:
Wanted output:
for arguments: 1,1 (col,row) the given answer will be: A
for arguments: 2,2 (col,row) the given answer will be: B,C
for arguments: 1,3 (col,row) the given answer will be: A,B
for arguments: 3,3 (col,row) the given answer will be: D

Thanks in advanced

Comment: I've try to think like the example that shown here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492590/using-bash-sed-awk-to-extract-rows-and-columns-in-csv-files

Answer (score 0):

`a.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

my $row_num = shift;
my $col_num = shift;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 });

while (my $row = $csv->getline(\*ARGV)) {
    next if --$row_num;

    print($row->[$col_num-1], "\n");
    last;
}
```

`a.csv`: (What you posted isn't a valid CSV, though Text::CSV_XS probably could handle it with the right options.)

```
A,B,C
A,"B,C",D
"A,B",C,D
A,B,"C,D"
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.pl 1 1 a.csv
A

$ ./a.pl 2 2 a.csv
B,C

$ ./a.pl 3 1 a.csv
A,B

$ ./a.pl 3 3 a.csv
D
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
If i try to simulate it to bash script like:

#!/bin/bash
COL=$1
ROW=$2
while IFS=',' read -r col1 col2 col3; do
     echo -e $col1
done < file.csv
IFS=$' \t\n'

but as you can see this is not what i need to do... i don't know how to tell the bash script to get only the relevant col a row..
Can you assist?

Comment: I try to do what you did but in bash script

Comment: @user5789818: Hint. You can't. There is no `Text::CSV_XS` module for bash

Comment: I know :)
I'm trying to do what this perl script does but in bash script..
I managed only get a headache until now.

Comment: What did you expect?  Rewriting 1000 lines of C code into bash code is not usually a piece of cake

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do that in bash script.. and I'll try until I will found the way :)
I don't give up so fast :) :)

Comment: Of course there is. Any program can be written in bash. Borodin was exaggerating. It doesn't mean it's easy. Again, covering 1000 lines of C code into bash is not easy. It works so so so much longer. How far have you gotten with your parser?