# How do I extract columns from CSV with quoted commas, using the shell?

Tags: bash, csv, text-processing, quoting

I have a CSV file, but unlike in [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492590/using-bash-sed-awk-to-extract-rows-and-columns-in-csv-files) questions, it has some columns containing double-quoted strings with commas, e.g.

```
foo,bar,baz,quux
11,"first line, second column",13.0,6
210,"second column of second line",23.1,5
```

(of course it's longer, and the number of quoted commas is not necessarily one or 0, nor is the text predictable.) The text might also have (escaped) double-quotes within double-quotes, or not have double-quotes altogether for a typically-quoted field. The only assumption we can make is that there are no quoted newlines, so we can split lines trivially using `\n`.

Now, I'd like to extract a specific column (say, the third one) - say, to be printed on standard output, one value per line. I can't simply use commas as field delimiters (and thus, e.g., use `cut`); rather, I need to something more sophisticated. What could that be?

Note: I'm using bash on a Linux system.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by 'quoted double-quotes' ?

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NF==5{$2=$2 OFS $3; $3=$4; $4=$5; NF=4} {print $3}' file`?

Comment: @NemanjaRadojković suggested [CSVKit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/). Seems rather useful, although not quite a "shell solution". Too bad he deleted his answer.

Comment: @oguzismail: I mean that "My name is \"John Smith\", what's yours?" can appear in the CSV.

Comment: @Cyrus: Why would this work?

Comment: To parse CSV with a mandatory POSIX tool that you can call from bash, see [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty Python `csvcut`.  The Python [`csv` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) already knows everything about various CSV dialects etc so you just need a thin wrapper.

The first argument should express the index of the field you wish to extract, like

```
csvcut 3 sample.csv
```

to extract the third column from the (possibly, quoted etc) CSV file `sample.csv`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv
import sys

writer=csv.writer(sys.stdout)
# Python indexing is zero-based
col = 1+int(sys.argv[1])
for input in sys.argv[2:]:
    with open(input) as handle:
        for row in csv.reader(handle): 
            writer.writerow(row[col])
```

To do: error handling, extraction of multiple columns. (Not hard per se; use `row[2:5]` to extract columns 3, 4, and 5; but I'm too lazy to write a proper command-line argument parser.)

Comment: csvcut is part of csvkit. It can be installed with the following command. `pip install csvkit`

Comment: Not _this_ `csvcut` of course; but yes, there are many implementations already, which is one of the reasons to not spend too much time on reinventing this.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for `FPAT`:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"([^"]|"")*"' '{print $3}' file.csv
baz
13.0
23.1
```

See [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for details and alternatives.