# How to Ignore a comma in CSV file using cut command

Tags: linux, csv, parsing, command-line, cut

sample.csv:-

```
sample,test,"Languages(Java","Rails)",1234,This-is-sample
```

3rd column has comma inside the value.

I am using following command to extract last 3 column values. But 5th column is not extracted. What I need to change in cut command to get the expected output?

```
cut -d "," -f 3-5 sample.csv
```

Exepected Output:-

```
"Languages(Java","Rails)",1234,This-is-sample
```

Actual Result:-

```
"Languages(Java,Rails)",1234
```

Comment: Your CSV sample isn't well-formed (or rather, it *is* well-formed, but the actual output is what you should expect with this input).  If you want the third field to contain `Languages(Java,Rails)` you should not have quotes around the comma.

Comment: Look into csvkit instead of cut.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use `cut` if the delimiter character also occurs inside values.  In CSV, double quotes around a field allows it to contain commas; you should use a tool which understands this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv
import sys

writer=csv.writer(sys.stdout)
for row in csv.reader(open("sample.csv")): 
    writer.writerow(row[2:5])
```

Comment: I posted a variant at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069852/874188 -- probably upvote that instead and ping me here, and I'll nominate this as a duplicate of that other question.