# Using awk command to filter out specific columns from a huge file

Tags: shell, awk

I'm currently working with a fairly large `csv` file that has 170 columns. I'd like to filter out three specific columns using `awk` filtering and then export that file out, so that the exported file only contains 3 out of 170 columns.

```
gzcat filename.csv.gz | awk '$19=="ACCOUNT_MOBILE_NUMBER" || $26=="DEVICE_ADID_TYPE" || $27=="DEVICE_ADID"' | gzip > filename_FILTERED.csv.gz
```

Expected results: new exported file containing only those three columns and their corresponding values/rows

Actual results so far: new exported file is blank

Comment: You need to provide a small snippet of your input file from `filename.csv.gz`

Comment: It's a csv... so it's comma-delimited, no? Try your `awk` again with the `-F,` flag.

Comment: Another way: `gunzip | cut`

Comment: Your script looks for lines which contain one of those values in the respective columns (and would print all columns if it finds one). Evidently the file does not contain any lines with exactly those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be looking for something more along the lines of:

```
gzcat filename.csv.gz |
awk -F, '{print $19,$26,$27}' |
gzip > filename_FILTERED.csv.gz
```

Comment: ... Though if the CSV contains quoting, you might need something slightly more involved, perhaps vaguely like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52466382/how-do-i-extract-column-from-csv-with-quoted-commas-using-the-shell

Comment: ... And if it doesn't, `cut -d, -f19,26,27` is probably faster as well as more legible than an Awk script.

Comment: cut -d function gave me what I needed. Thank you everyone